# yarn gives error when creating react application

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I get the below error when running "**yarn create react-app app**"

I understand that this is because of the spaces present in my system username . How do I run this command such that I don't have to change my system username

```
success Installed "create-react-app@2.1.3" with binaries:
      - create-react-app
[################################################################] 
64/64'C:\Users\ted' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\ted mosby\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
Arguments: app
Directory: D:\Projects\react
```

I can't find the application in the above mentioned directory

Comment: if your creating app then use `create-react-app <appName>` not `yarn create react-app <appName>`

Comment: Submit a bug report to yarn. Usernames with spaces really should be supported in 2019... BTW, `yarn create react-app app` **is** the correct syntax.

Comment: Does `npm init react-app app` work?

Answer (score 8):

**This method is just a workaround.**

On Windows, if your user profile has a space in it which it often has since Windows wants your full name.

For example:

`C:\Users\John Doe`

Running yarn create next-app will fail with

`'C:\Users\John' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

If setting cache folder for `yarn` and `npm` does not seem to work, try changing the environment variable `LOCALAPPDATA` which points to the app data in your home directory.

First, check 8.3 directory name with

```
dir C:\Users /x
```

`C:\Users\John` should look like `C:\Users\JOHN~1`.

Then, set the environment variable with

```
set LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\JOHN~1\AppData\Local
```

Now, `yarn create` should work.

Comment: setting the cache and package using npm instead of yarn worked for me:
npm config set cache-folder "C:\Users\JOHN~1\AppData\Local" --global
npm config set prefix "C:\Users\JOHN~1\AppData\Local" --global

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from:

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5717

You may have a chance by upgrading to Node 11.1.0 (and, one assumes, higher) or using yarn 1.5.1 instead. (I would definitely encourage attempting the Node upgrade first. You may want to look into https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows to manage your node versions sensibly.)

I'm sure these issues are related, but adding your use-case may well encourage work to accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users with `space in their username`, this is still an open [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6630) and here is the as workaround mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6630#issuecomment-536436066).

```
yarn config set cache-folder c:\root\yarn\cache
yarn config set prefix c:\root\yarn\packages
```